# Electricity blew out after touching with metal object

Tags: transformer

I touched the electrical portion that connects to LED light bulb with metal object. The entire lighting blew out. Did I destroy transformer?

Comment: Decent chance.  One reason that turning off the breaker is recommended when poking electrical devices with metal objects, or fingers/tongues.

Comment: Did you simply trip the breaker? Have you checked it?

Comment: probably not, that is why a breaker is there

Answer (score 1):

If it's a cheap transformer, there's a good chance you blew an internal fuse that cannot be replaced. More expensive transformers will have fuses that can be replaced or a reset button.

Comment: what is the price threshold

Comment: Price will vary a lot depending on output and geography. If you, @Traveler are the OP, you should request that your accounts be merged. And take a photo of the transformer after you check your breakers.